# PayPal IPN is enabled, but logs are showing nothing received and the IPN history simply shows a blank HTTP Status Code

Tags: paypal, paypal-ipn

Normally, I would post this in a PayPal discussion board; however, their website has seemingly sent me to stack overflow...

So, i've been working my way through the PayPal IPN response flow.  Everything has been going great up until I attempted live testing. I have been able to set it up locally and test it accordingly.  I released it to a publicly facing test environment and the IPN Sandbox worked flawlessly.  Now, I'm attempting a full test using my actual credit card and I'm seemingly never receiving an IPN.

I've gone in and verified that IPN is currently turned on.  I am setting a custom IPN callback URL via the button's hidden notify_url functionality.  I am able to go through the purchase process and I can see the new IPN is added to the IPN History list.  The IPN has the appropriate callback URL that I would expect; however, it seemingly never receives an IPN message.

To verify, I did a couple of things.  As a quick foreword about my environment, I'm working on an AWS Lambda instantiated Kestrel server that is accessible via API Gateway.  I've added logging at the API Gateway layer and can verify that no IPN message are ever being received.  At this point, I had assumed that there was something wrong with my IPN configuration.  I copied both the IPN callback and the payload from the IPN history into Postman.  Postman was able to hit my API without issue and everything processed successfully; I was able to see all of the logs from this activity at both the API Gateway layer and the Lambda application layer.

Another possible issue that popped into my mind was CORS; however, I've had multiple issues with CORS in the past with this project and have set my Options pre-flight to simply allow all remote hosts.

Any suggestions as to what's happening here?  Everything appears to be configured correctly; however, I'm not seeing any post ever occur from PayPal.

---

EDIT 1: After a bit of experimentation, it appears that if I set my notify_url to use HTTP instead of HTTPS, the callback finally came through. HTTPS is enabled on my website and I have a valid certificate that should have been authorized via Amazon as the CA. Why switching to HTTP makes this work; I have absolutely no idea. I'd prefer HTTPS if possible; any suggestions to allow me to fix this would be awesome.

---

EDIT 2: I was reading through PayPal documentation about their fee structure and had started to think that maybe my $0.01 test purchase was getting eaten up by the fees.  I expected as much; however, I realized the $0.01 test purchase was technically not covering the full costs associated with the purchase.  I decided I would try to update the cost to $1.00 under the inclination that the unmet fee balance may have caused the issue. (~3% + $0.30) As soon as I updated my price to be $1.00, it seemed like my HTTPS call started working.  I'm wondering if there's a floor price of about $0.33 required to use HTTPS over IPN; perhaps the call will not complete correctly unless the entire fee structure is covered?

Answer (score 0):

I would advise you to file an MTS ticket. You may go to the link below:
https://www.paypal-techsupport.com/app/ask

We will assist you further on the issue.

Thank you

Comment: I've got an issue filed there, but nobody has gotten back to me yet and I can't really move on to a new feature until this is fixed. After poking around the PayPal website, I was routed here and was hoping a community user might have an idea.